Duplicated value and comparison between two objects
I have this fn into a react component
I need to make a comparison and return = true if the newMOF is extrictly equals to any of the element on the existingMOFs array
 array//This fn is responsbale to check if the MOF alredy exist. If it does, return true.
  const isDuplicateMOF = (existingMOFs:MaterialOnTheFly[], newMOF: MaterialOnTheFly): boolean => {  
    return existingMOFs.some (existingMOF => {
 
      if (existingMOF.manufactureDetail.manufactureDetailPublicId !== newMOF.manufactureDetail.manufactureDetailPublicId) {
        //No need to further comparison since manufacture details don't match
        return false  
      }
 
      if (existingMOF.compositions?.length !== newMOF.compositions?.length) {
        //Check if compositions have the same length
        return false
      }

      return xxxxxx
      });
    });
  };

This is the type:
type MaterialOnTheFly = {
  compositions: {[
   percentage: number;
   rawMaterial: {
    isDeleted: boolean;
    rawMaterialName: string;
    rawMaterialPublicId: string;
  };
 ]};
  manufactureDetail: {
   isDeleted: boolean;
   manufactureDetailName: string;
   manufactureDetailPublicId: string;
  };
  materialOnTheFlyPublicId: string;
  materialSubcategory: {
   isDeleted: boolean;
   materialSubcategoryName: string;
   materialSubcategoryPublicId: string;
  };
};

I have tried both with a loop for and then with a .every method but I really don't know how to make it in a dynamic and efficeint way.
** First attempt not correct
     for (let i = 0; i < existingMOF.compositions?.length; i++){
      if((existingMOF.compositions[i]?.rawMaterial?.rawMaterialName === newMOF.compositions[i]?.rawMaterial?.rawMaterialName) &&
        (existingMOF.compositions[i]?.percentage === newMOF.compositions[i]?.percentage))
        return true
     }

** Second attempt not correct
    return existingMOF.compositions.every((existingComposition, index) => {
      const newComposition = newMOF.compositions[index];
      return existingComposition.rawMaterial.rawMaterialName === newComposition.rawMaterial.rawMaterialName &&
             existingComposition.percentage === newComposition.percentage;


Does this answer your question? Javascript - Check if arrays within an array are the same

I don't know how large these objects are, but if you want a really stupid way to check if they contain the same data, you can stringify them and compare the strings so that you're not stuck looping through and checking multiple properties of multiple objects one by one. Here's a very basic example of the concept:


var objA = { a: 1, b: 47, c: [{a: 132, b: 33}]}

var objB = { a: 1, b: 47, c: [{a: 132, b: 33}]}

console.log(JSON.stringify(objA) === JSON.stringify(objB))




Thanks Jon for the solution, but I can't use it. The object is quite a bog one, with lots of nested things, and it should be more dynamic

@FedericoGiannini I'm not sure what you mean by dynamic if you're looking for exact matches? This would go into the loop that you have already as a way of comparing the new MOF to the existing list of them - rather than checking 2 properties as an indicator that they match, this would directly check that they match entirely

I mean dynamic in the sense that if I add a new value to the object, I don't want to add it  even to the loop. Right now, the loop that I crated is comparing just two value (rawMaterialName and Percentage) but the object is quite bigger than that.
And I wouldn't like to create a loop with 5 or 6 comparison!!

Hey Jon. I changed the logic and I followed your suggestion and right now it is working fine. Thanks
